# Nginx reverse proxy to hide my real servers

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

I have 2 servers, both using nginx.

Server 1: `192.168.xxx.xxx` (This is the main server with the mydomain.com domain with LEMP)

Server 2: `128.111.xxx.xxx` (which will come)

On the first server I used Cloudflare to hide the server IP. But that apparently didn't really hide it.

So I got advice in the form of something like this.

> Another way, you can buy a another server and use it as a reverse proxy to your main server.

So my question is, how to make this happen?

I want all traffic to go through server 2 first, which I plan to use as a reverse proxy before forwarding it to server 1. That way the IP on the main server will not be visible even in certain ways.

I only understand a little about Nginx, and I've read several articles and similar cases but I still don't understand how to make it happen.

---

Updates:

I have managed to `proxy_pass` server2 to server1, but since it is on server1 I use it for multiple domains. And I put the several config in server1 `/etc/nginx/sites-available` , `proxy_pass` on the server2 points to server1 `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

Where "**default**" is the default config which, if the IP is accessed, will lead to the default Welcome to Nginx page!
And also some config **domain1, domain2, domain3** and so on. What I want to do is `proxy_pass` server2 to server1 which points to the config **domain1** is in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1`.

But what I get in server2 config, server2 does `proxy_pass` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, not to **domain1**.

Here is the config that I have, where is it wrong?

Server2 config:

```
    upstream backend {
        server server1_IP;
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
```

server1 config default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/master/master.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/master/master.key;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.nginx-debian.html index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Server1 domain1.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain1.com/domain1.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain1.com/domain1.com.key;
    root /var/www/html/domain1.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com.error.log;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (BLEXBot|GrapeshotCrawler|MJ12bot|SemrushBot|AhrefsBot|DotBot) ) { return 301 http://127.0.0.1/; }
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.(asp|bat|cgi|htm|html|ico|js|jsp|md|php|pl|py|sh|shtml|swf|twig|txt|yaml|yml|zip|gz|tar|bzip2|7z)$ { deny all; }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/tmp/:/usr/share/php/:/dev/urandom:/dev/shm:/var/lib/php/sessions/:$document_root";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-domain1.com-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location = /wp-login.php {
        limit_req zone=limit burst=1 nodelay;
        limit_req_status 429;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-domain1.com-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /\.us {
        deny all;
    }
        location ~* "(base64_encode)(.*)(\()" {
        deny all;
        }
        location ~* "(eval\()" {
        deny all;
        }
    location = /xmlrpc.php {
        return 403;
    }
    rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;



}
```

For domain2, 3 and so on the same as domain 1.

So basically I want proxy_pass to domain1 from server2 not to the default. Which later I will enter the IP on server2 into Cloudflare's A record.

So even if someone can find my server IP address even using Cloudflare they will only read the IP of server2 not server1.

Comment: Run nginx on server 2, and config the `proxy_pass` to server 1.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Check the demo in my answer, hope it will helps.

Comment: If you use multi server on server 1. In the upstream you need to distinguish them. One way is by ip and port, another way is by servername.

Comment: How to distinguish them? My config are above, can you make example same as my config?

Comment: Read the nginx manual.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward the server2's traffic to server1, config server2's nginx config like below.

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server backend1.example.com;
        #server backend2.example.com;
        #server backend3.example.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

        # if you want to config different backend
        location /a/ {
            proxy_pass adifferentbackend;
        }
    }

    # if you have other server
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain1

        location / {
            proxy_pass subdomainserver;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, because I use Cloudflare for DNS, I'm a little confused.

For the config you provided, it means the section "server backend1.example.com;" I only need to enter server IP 1 then "server_name example.com;" I enter the current domain name, then the IP of server 2 just needs to be entered into the Cloudflare A record? Is it like that?

Comment: Yes. It's right. And nginx also support config ip directly.

Comment: Sir, one more question. It's working fine. I have successfully redirected traffic from server 1 to server 2, but there is a slight problem. On server 2 I use it for several sites. And I have /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, domain1, domain2, and so on.

So, in the case above, I didn't succeed in reaching the domain I was aiming for, but instead it went to "default" which displays the "Welcome to Nginx!" page.

Comment: If you have many domain name, you can config each domain name a server block with domain name as the server_name in it.
If you have one domain name, and you can config different uri prefix for each behind domain with nginx location directives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. But please check my question again, I have updated it. Because it is limited to comments here.